# Setting up a JS file to get its function triggered

Tags: javascript

I’m learning JavaScript and in a few scripts that I have come across I can see a reference to what seems like apis and then functions. For example:

```
      // Call the what3words
      what3words.api
        .gridSectionGeoJson({
          southwest: {
            lat: sw.lat,
            lng: sw.lng
          },
          northeast: {
            lat: ne.lat,
            lng: ne.lng
          }
        })
```

I’ve tried to replicate this by swapping this code out for my own version by doing the following:

1. Remove what3words.js
2. Include my own script file script.js in the headers for that page
3. Include a function inside that file, such as this:

---

```
function gridSectionGeoJson() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World!";
}
```

However this never gets triggered. How do I setup my script.js so that my function gets triggered by the code in the top snippet? I imagine that has to do with the reference to “what3words.api” that I need to somehow designate inside my own JS file to get it to trigger.

Comment: `what3words.api.gridSectionGeoJson` is likely executed at load of the file - you do not have a trigger

Comment: This is very confusing and very much sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What is the higher level issue you are trying to solve? Trying to extend the `what3words.api` object to trigger your code is not trivial

Comment: Hello. I don’t want to extend it, I want to swap it out but I can’t get my own code to execute

Comment: So you would get rid of all that is shown and just call your function there .... `gridSectionGeoJson()`. Or insert that function call above or below the `what3words.api.gridSectionGeoJson()` call if you want it to continue to run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the script block above you would just call `gridSectionGeoJson();` given the script you have above. You typically want to include all scripts at the end of the page when possible.

Comment: So really what3words.api does nothing? I can just remove this and also remove the period at the start of the function .gridSectionGeoJson();. I can instead just use your example to call the function

Comment: That is essentially a namespace. It's the old way that people did js modules before ES6 and webpack changed everything.